# Toggle Multiple Image Overlays in Google Maps v3 using Checkboxes

Tags: google-maps-api-3, checkbox, overlay, jquery

Please give me a piece of advice.

I'm trying to create a map with multiple image overlays. I'd like to show/hide each overlays by checking the checkbox. I used [GeoJason's code](http://geojason.info/2010/overlay-map-management-with-google-maps-api-v3/) as a reference, but for some reason, it doesn't work properly for me: whether checked or unchecked, no layer appears. Please tell me what's wrong with my code.

This is script part.

```
<script>
var server = 'https://gbank.gsj.jp/seamless/tilemap/';
var geolMapType = 'basic';
var layer = 'glfn';
var opacity = 0.7;
var map;

function initialize() {
 var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 7,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.59, 135.67),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  minZoom: 5,
  maxZoom: 13
 };

 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

 overlayMaps = [
    { //sedTer
    getTileUrl: function (coord, z) {
    return server + geolMapType + '/' + layer + '/' + z + '/' + coord.y + '/' + coord.x + '.png' + '?select=gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    isPng: true
    }, { //sedMar
    getTileUrl: function (coord, z) {
    return server + geolMapType + '/' + layer + '/' + z + '/' + coord.y + '/' + coord.x + '.png' + '?select=_____AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwBAIEIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    isPng: true
    }, { //accSed
    getTileUrl: function (coord, z) {
    return server + geolMapType + '/' + layer + '/' + z + '/' + coord.y + '/' + coord.x + '.png' + '?select=gAAAA______4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    isPng: true
    }, { //accMaf
    getTileUrl: function (coord, z) {
    return server + geolMapType + '/' + layer + '/' + z + '/' + coord.y + '/' + coord.x + '.png' + '?select=gAAAAAAAAAAH-AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    isPng: true
    }, { //volTep
    getTileUrl: function (coord, z) {
    return server + geolMapType + '/' + layer + '/' + z + '/' + coord.y + '/' + coord.x + '.png' + '?select=gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    isPng: true
    }, { //volDeb
    getTileUrl: function (coord, z) {
    return server + geolMapType + '/' + layer + '/' + z + '/' + coord.y + '/' + coord.x + '.png' + '?select=gAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    isPng: true
    }, { //volInt
    getTileUrl: function (coord, z) {
    return server + geolMapType + '/' + layer + '/' + z + '/' + coord.y + '/' + coord.x + '.png' + '?select=gAAAAAAAAAAAAeAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAehwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    isPng: true
    }, { //pluFel
    getTileUrl: function (coord, z) {
    return server + geolMapType + '/' + layer + '/' + z + '/' + coord.y + '/' + coord.x + '.png' + '?select=gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP_-AAAAAAgAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    isPng: true
    }, { //pluMaf
    getTileUrl: function (coord, z) {
    return server + geolMapType + '/' + layer + '/' + z + '/' + coord.y + '/' + coord.x + '.png' + '?select=gAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAD_-AAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    isPng: true
    }, { //pluMig
    getTileUrl: function (coord, z) {
    return server + geolMapType + '/' + layer + '/' + z + '/' + coord.y + '/' + coord.x + '.png' + '?select=gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    isPng: true
    }, { //all
    getTileUrl: function (coord, z) {
    return server + geolMapType + '/' + layer + '/' + z + '/' + coord.y + '/' + coord.x + '.png';
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    isPng: true,
    opacity: 0.2
    }
];

$('.layer').click(function(){
 var layerID = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
 if ($(this).attr('checked')){
  var overlayMap = new google.maps.ImageMapType(overlayMaps[layerID]);
  map.overlayMapTypes.setAt(layerID, overlayMap);
  }
 else {
  if (map.overlayMapTypes.getLength() > 0){
  map.overlayMapTypes.setAt(layerID, null);
  }
 }
});

for (i = 0; i < overlayMaps.length; i++){
 map.overlayMapTypes.push(null);
}

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

And this is HTML code.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="00" class="layer" name="sedTer" /><label for="00">Sedimentary Rocks, Terrace</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="01" class="layer" name="sedMar" /><label for="01">Sedimentary Rocks, Non-marine&amp;Marine</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="02" class="layer" name="accSed" /><label for="02">Accretionary Complexes, Mainly sedimentary rocks</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="03" class="layer" name="accMaf" /><label for="03">Accretionary Complexes, Mafic</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="04" class="layer" name="volTep" /><label for="04">Volcanic Rocks, Tephra</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="05" class="layer" name="volDeb" /><label for="05">Volcanic Rocks, Debris</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="06" class="layer" name="volInt" /><label for="06">Volcanic Rocks, Intrusive</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="07" class="layer" name="pluFel" /><label for="07">Plutonic Rocks, Felsic</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="08" class="layer" name="pluMaf" /><label for="08">Plutonic Rocks, Mafic</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="09" class="layer" name="pluMig" /><label for="09">Plutonic Rocks, Migmatitic</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="10" class="layer" name="all" /><label for="10">All</label><br />
```

Please, no flames about my bad English. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is this:

```
if ($(this).attr('checked'))
```

when you click a checkbox, the `checked`-attribute of a checkbox will not change.

But the `checked`-property will, use this instead:

```
if ($(this).prop('checked'))
```